# jQuery querying the database

Tags: jquery

The thing is that there are number of items in the HTML select list. I want to click on any of the items, then query the database on the id of that item, retrieve the value and then display that in the textbox. How would I query the database?

I would really appreciate that if someone provides a code sample for querying the database.

Comment: What's the backend technology that accesses the database?  PHP, Perl, ASP, etc?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you weren't trying to access the database from javascript or jquery.  You'll be fine with creating a asp.net script to access the database and returning the desired contents in either a XML or JSON format in conjunction with the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have jquery fire an ajax call to your server. Your server is what will actually query the database.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$.get('/ajaxquery/yourselectvalue', function(data) {
  $('#yourTextBox').val(data);
});
```